# VBA Inbut box with loop

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I have just started learning VBA (and coding in general) and I am faced with a problem to which I have not yet found a solution. I'd like to create an input box with a loop so that the output from the input box will be printed to separate cell. For example, I would like to write number "5" to the input box and the output will be printed to Cell "A1" and the next input, say number "9", will be printed to Cell "A2".

So far, I have managed to this and everything works fine except the last row as I don't know how to continue from here.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim myValue As Variant

myValue = InputBox("Please insert number")

Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Value = myValue

Range(ActiveCell) = Range(ActiveCell) + 1

End Sub
```

All help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim myValue As Variant
    myValue = InputBox("Please insert number")
    Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = myValue
End Sub
```

**EDIT #1:**
Updated the code as per the advice of user3598756

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim myValue As Variant
    myValue = InputBox("Please insert number")
    If Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value = "" Then
        Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) = myValue
    Else
        Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = myValue
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was exactly the one I was looking for.

Comment: @VilleT, then your question was misleading since you started from cell "A1" downwards while this solution skips cell "A1"

Comment: @user3598756. purposely thats for header.

Comment: @VilleT, Welcome always.

Comment: @KarthickGunasekaran no sign of this "purpose" in the OP's question

Comment: @user3598756,   the code was exactly the one I was looking for. I was using "A1" as an example.

Answer (score 1):

**edited** to

- shorten the code
- add solution should cell "A1" be already filled with header

the following code will do:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
        .Offset(IIf(.Value <> "", 1, 0)) = InputBox("Please insert number")
    End With
End Sub
```

where the "conditional" offset is necessary to manage the first empty cell being in row 1 (no offset) or lower (1 row offset)

should cell "A1" be already filled with header, the code shortens down to:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = InputBox("Please insert number")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a loop - for example 10 times - then you can use this example code:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim myValue As Variant


    For counter = 1 To 10
        myValue = InputBox("Please insert number")
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(counter, 1).Value = myValue
    Next counter

End Sub
```